# Mastering Joomla

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I am planning to develop a portal using Joomla cms.

The portal has to be fully customized.

I would like to know some best tutorials and books for Joomla CMS customization.

Thanks

Comment: what's your level in php and joomla knowledge so far?

Comment: what's a fully customized portal in your opinion? examples? (because fully customized to me sounds more like you don't want to use joomla.)

Answer (score 2):

Really the best thing I've tried - and believe me  I tried a lot - is by using Lynda.com. Its very cheap and it has some really great video tutorials about Joomla. You can also learn how to develop modules and components if you are an OOP developer.

http://www.lynda.com/search?q=joomla&x=0&y=0

Also for books I would suggest the "officials" from Core Devs of the Joomla Platform

[Joomla-Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Joomla-Programming-Press-Mark-Dexter/dp/013278081X/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=1N0N4FB003F78&coliid=I3UBHB5QXECUW4)

[Joomla-Templates by Angie Radtke](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Joomla-Templates-Angie-Radtke/dp/0321827317/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=1N0N4FB003F78&coliid=I3RDT3HACXB1DQ)

Answer (score 1):

In this order:

1. Joomla! 1.5: A User's Guide: Building a Successful Joomla! Powered Website (2nd Edition) by Barrie M. North
2. Joomla! 1.5 Template Design by Tessa Blakeley Silver
3. Learning Joomla! 1.5 Extension Development by Joseph LeBlanc
4. Mastering Joomla! 1.5 Extension and Framework Development: The Professional Guide to Programming Joomla! by James Kennard

Where you start on that list depends on your current ability and what your goals are.  #1 is for beginners.  If you want to do template design and already know html and css, then #2 is the place to start.  If you are doing custom module and components and you already know PHP, then start with #3 and #4.

Answer (score 0):

[HowToJoomla](http://www.howtojoomla.net/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing modules or components, the offical Joomla! wiki is by no means exhaustive, but can be useful for some common tasks. Check the 'Developers' section.

There are some decent tutorials at jlleblanc.com here:
http://www.jlleblanc.com/content/blogcategory/0/51/

If you're a bit more of a hardened dev, then the Joomla API docs can be useful, but I do admit they're hard to browse (it's not always obvious which package any given class will be in), so it's often easier to search them using Google or similar.

Answer (score 0):

And there is [Joomla! 1.7 - Beginner's Guide](http://cocoate.com/j17) in several languages.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla's documentation is mainly aimed at 1.5 right now.  The API is not as documented as it could be, with a lot of method names that are things like printfooter() and the documentation says 'prints the footer' (I'm looking at you, pagination class).

The books recommended above are solid.  There is a 1.7 MVC component tutorial as well that leaves out details, but between that and careful reading of source code and the Joomla API you can slowly get something out of it.

The biggest hurdle is going to be memorization.  Lots of Joomla Class methods are not intuitive or the best documented (for instance, using the _() setup to run lots of arbitrary class/method combinations).